# How can add signature to pdf with laravel 5.5 laravel-snappy

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, signature, laravel-snappy

I'm using Laravel 5.5 laravel-snappy to create PDF.
I just wanted to add a signature in my PDF.
I am not able to find nothing, is any pluging or something for that?
Thanks

Comment: Signature image or a digital signature?

Answer (score 0):

In your pdf template, you could have an image of the signature (With transparant background i.e `png`) or signature text at the bottom and control its appearance as you like.  for example `opacity`, `size` etc.

But if you want to digitally sign your pdf then you can use [tcpdf](https://github.com/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel)